# What's the uplink port shows in the `show interfaces terse`?

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos, juniper-ex

My Juniper EX4300 have four uplink port:

[image]

but when I show interface, there only two `xe` port:

```
Interface       Admin Link

gr-0/0/0        up    up
pfe-0/0/0       up    up
pfe-0/0/0.16383 up    up    inet
                            inet6
pfh-0/0/0       up    up
pfh-0/0/0.16383 up    up    inet
                            inet6
...
xe-0/2/0        up    down
xe-0/2/0.16386  up    down
...
```

I have some questions:

1) What's the uplink port shows in the `show interfaces terse`?
2) What's the `gr-0/0/0`, `pfe-0/0/0` , `pfh-0/0/0` stand for?
3）What's the difference between `pfh-0/0/0` and `pfh-0/0/0.16386`?

Comment: The four "uplink" ports are QSFP (40Gbit/s) ports. They can be configured for native 40G (*et*, *xle*, or *fte* for data-plane uplink mode) or split into four 10G interfaces each (*xe*) using a fanout cable.

Comment: We'd need to see more of the inventory/config. There are 4 QSFP+ on the back, and the picture shows a 4 SFP+ module on the front.

Comment: @Zac67 officially they can't be split - did you do that with success?

Comment: @FlorianHeigl That seems correct - the EX4300 series doesn't support "channelizing" the QSFP+ ports. No, I don't use one of those switches.

Comment: @Zac67 Thanks for your feedback - it would have been really cool ;-)